# Internal Server Error by calling C# function with jQuery Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In my application i have two ImageButtons. In the OnClientClick event of them i call the js above js function. As paramter i give strings like 'en' or 'de'.

### Javascript Code:

```
    //Blocks the submit of the form and changes the language
    function changeLanguage(languageIdentifier)
    {
        var pageUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("default.aspx/changeLanguage") %>';
        var parameter = '{ "languageIdentifier": languageIdentifier }';

        //Call the C# Methods
        $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: pageUrl, data: parameter, contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json", failure: function (response) { alert(response.data) } }).done(function () { alert("Language was changed.") }).fail(function (jqXHR, errorText, errorThrown) { alert("An error has occurred: " + errorThrown); });

        return false;
    }
```

### C# Code:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static bool changeLanguage(string languageIdentifier)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get the whole formular
            Page thisPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
            //Get the informations from the formular
            Brain.UserRequest = _default.getUserGivenInformation(thisPage);

            //Change session values
            switch (languageIdentifier)
            {
                case "DE":
                case "de-DE":
                case "de": HttpContext.Current.Session["uiculture"] = "de";
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["culture"] = "de-DE";
                    break;
                case "EN":
                case "en-GB":
                case "en":
                default: HttpContext.Current.Session["uiculture"] = "en";
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["culture"] = "en-GB";
                    break;
            }

            //Reloads the page
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery, false);

            return true;
        }
        catch 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

After clicking the ImageButton the C# method will not called. Only a error message like "An error has occurred: Internal Server Error" appears. Do anyone know why there is the problem?

### Edit:

Now i have replaced the `HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer` code and have insert two response write methods.

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string changeLanguage(string languageIdentifier) 
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Test #default.changeLanguage");

        try
        {
            //Get the whole formular
            Page thisPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
            //Get the informations from the formular
            Brain.UserRequest = _default.getUserGivenInformation(thisPage);

            //Change session values
            switch (languageIdentifier)
            {
                case "DE":
                case "de-DE":
                case "de": HttpContext.Current.Session["uiculture"] = "de";
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["culture"] = "de-DE";
                    break;
                case "EN":
                case "en-GB":
                case "en":
                default: HttpContext.Current.Session["uiculture"] = "en";
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["culture"] = "en-GB";
                    break;
            }

            //Create url for redirecting
            string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

            return url;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(e.Message + " #default.changeLanguage");
            return "";
        }
    }
```

But no failor from the C# Code appears. I have found this error messages from chrome

[Failor Picture on Onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=876407350E6B332D!1435&authkey=!AKhvRWGZU3z1Auk&ithint=folder%2C)

For me it seams that the C# function will not found.

Comment: You should debug your server code to find out what throws the error.

Comment: Debug your web method and catch the error, we can't really guess what the error might be. Although your "reload the page" code at most will do nothing usefull, you can't cause the browser to reload the page from server side code unless you use something like signalr

Comment: can not do HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer using ajax

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer` this is for sure throw an error, also here `Page thisPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler` you do not get actually the page you believe, so the next function may also fail.

Comment: can not do HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer using ajax.This is not your answer but this method  is worthless..Actually methos has to return string of URL..and can do redirect using that URL in jquery

Comment: OK, thanks for your comments. I will try something and write the result here.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScriptCode**

```
function changeLanguage(languageIdentifier) {
        var pageUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("/demo.aspx/changeLanguage") %>';
        var params={};
        params.languageIdentifier=languageIdentifier;
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(params);

        //Call the C# Methods
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl,
            data: jsonString,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert("Language was changed.");
            }
        })

        return false;
    }
```

**.aspx code**

```
<div>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbutn" runat="server" Height="50" Width="50" OnClientClick="return changeLanguage('en')" />
    </div>
```

**Code Behind Page**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) // to check page is post back or not
        {
            // do stuff here


        }

        if (Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")  // this is to check whether it's an AJAX call or not
        {
            // do stuff here..
        }
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static bool changeLanguage(string languageIdentifier)
    {
        // do logic here....
        return true;
    }
```

I just checked its working fine. 
Hope it helps you.